# mongoskin select special fields rather than all

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

I'm looking for a way to get special fields from mongoskin find function. in other words in SQL lang we say select column1,column2,column3 from mytable rather than select *

currently my query is like below and i want to get specify the fields that I'm looking for rather the the whole json object.

```
db.collection('collacta').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (result) {
                ...
            } else {
                ...
            };
        });
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the projection of fields, you should pass the DBObject for projection,

```
DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query, projectionQuery);
```

The projection is The DBObject in form of key-value pair. where,

key is the name of field you want to project. value can be either 0 or 1.
0 - means exclude the particular column from result set.
1 - means include the particular column in result set.

For more info, see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/).